Is there any indication that China is fuelling the unrest in Manipur of India?
Recently, high-tech drones and rocket propelled grenades have been used by Kuki insurgents in the north-eastern state of Manipur in India.
The following photo shows an artillery rocket (also aftermath video):

And a launcher.
Is there any indication that China is directly or indirectly fuelling the unrest in Manipur, India?

Interesting that you voted to close your own Q.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever, Coz, I wanted to deprive other people of answering this question.


directly or indirectly

Hard to say for certain, but as Wikipedia will tell you the Kuki rebels span India and neighboring Myanmar, where there's a civil war going on. Certainly more hi-tech weapons (than RPGs) have been acquired by some rebel groups in Myanmar, including MANPADS of Chinese make etc.
Certainly Myanmar's military has purchased plenty of Chinese weapons, at least in the past. The rebels have captured some of those, but there's also suspicion in the Western press that China may be 'playing both sides' on some level, at least in that it has an interest in the rebels acting as China's private police abroad in suppressing some criminal operations that affect China (drug trade, phone scams, etc.)

These ethnic armies are not straightforward Chinese proxies. They advance their own interests, including by gaining territory, while aligning themselves with other groups that are less friendly to China, such as Myanmar’s increasingly well-organised pro-democracy faction. Yet China has periodically pulled their strings, with the recent [late 2023] offensive apparently a case in point. On December 10th it sought to capitalise on the militias’ advance by issuing arrest warrants for ten scam bosses operating in northern Myanmar. Four days later, apparently content that its objective had been served, it brokered the ceasefire.

Another article points out that it was mostly the groups in the north of Myanmar (bordering China and India) that have made advances against the junta, while those in the south seeking Western support through Thailand didn't have much luck. This article also claims that the Brotherhood Alliance "is made up of three groups, all of which get support from China", however the Kukis don't seem to be formally part of this Brotherhood Alliance.
More than a decade ago, China was suspected of aiding the Wa rebels (then described as "Burma's largest rebel group"), including with surface-to-air missiles, some armored vehicles, and even helicopters. (The helicopter rumour was dismissed initially, but later turned to be somewhat true--in the sense that they were civilian.) The level of Chinese influence & support appears somewhat proportional with the Sinicization of these groups.
